# How can I add a picture to the DetailView template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I built an website and used my model 'Post' in the DetailView CBV.
I have another Model called: 'UserProfileInfo' in which I have a imagefield.
I want to display the post author pic next to his name in the post_detail template.
How can I do this? I know I cant specify 2 models as the models in the DetailView function.. I thought about adding it to the get_context_data view somehow.. I dont realy know.

The relevant code:

Models:

```
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, models.PROTECT)
# mode ls.PROTECT is an on_delete value which protect the source model and if he is not existed or having a problem he raises an Error to alert us

    # additional
    portfolio_site = models.URLField(blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='TheApp/profile_pics',blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    post_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)



    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("TheApp:post_detail", kwargs={'pk':self.pk})


    def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

The view:

```
class PostDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):

    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        obj = self.get_object()
        obj.post_views = obj.post_views + 1
        obj.save()
        return context
```

The template:

```
{% extends "TheApp/base.html" %}

{% block body_block %}


<div class="container" style="margin-top:50px; margin-bottom:20px;">
  <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>

<div style="margin-bottom:20px;">{{ post.create_date }}</div>


<p>{{ post.text }}</p>

<p>Created By: {{ post.author }}</p>



{% if user.is_authenticated %}

  <a class='btn btn-primary btn-comment' href="{% url 'TheApp:add_comment_to_post' pk=post.pk %}">Add Comment</a>



  {% if user == post.author %}

    <a class='btn btn-primary' href="{% url 'TheApp:post_edit' pk=post.pk %}">EDIT</a>

    <a class='btn btn-primary' href="{% url 'TheApp:post_remove' pk=post.pk %}">DELETE</a>

  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
</div>

<div class="container" style="margin-bottom:150px;">
  {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
  <div class="Misgeret" style= "margin-bottom:20px;">

  <br>
  {{comment.create_date}}
  <p>{{comment.text|linebreaks}}</p> 
  <p>Posted by: {{comment.author}}</p>



  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% if user.username == comment.author or user == post.author %}

    <a style="margin-bottom:20px;" class='btn btn-primary' href="{% url 'TheApp:comment_remove' pk=comment.pk %}">Remove</a>


  {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
  {% empty %}
  <p>No Comments</p>
  {% endfor %}


</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: With `<img src="{{ post.author.userprofileinfo.profile_pic.url }}">`

Comment: Ok first I have no error so its good.. but how can I go to userprofileinfo from post.author?
Second, the pic is not displayed.. maybe something with my settings? or should I load it? I need to load the media like I did with the static files?

Comment: My settings are:
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/me_blog/media/'

And the profile_pic directory is at: me_blog\media\TheApp\profile_pics

Comment: Not working bro.. any idea?